# how to solve Property does not exist on type 'never' for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

hi guys i am new to typescript i want to ask why i am keep getting this error.please tell me in detail how to solve this because i am still learning about typescript.do you know how to solve this error?
what i need to add or change to solve this error?

here's the error on //handle save:

> Property 'getImage' does not exist on type 'never'.

```
import { Box, Modal, Slider, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor";
import { FcAddImage } from "react-icons/fc";
import { AiFillGithub } from "react-icons/ai";
import "./Cropper.scss";


// Styles
const boxStyle = {
  width: "300px",
  height: "300px",
  display: "flex",
  flexFlow: "column",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};
const modalStyle = {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

// Modal
const CropperModal = ({ src, modalOpen, setModalOpen, setPreview }:{src:any, modalOpen:any, setModalOpen:any, setPreview:any}) => {
  const [slideValue, setSlideValue] = useState(10);
  const cropRef = useRef(null);
  

  //handle save
  const handleSave = async () => {
    if (cropRef.current !== null) {
      const dataUrl = cropRef.current.getImage().toDataURL();
      const result = await fetch(dataUrl);
      const blob = await result.blob();
      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      setModalOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal sx={modalStyle} open={modalOpen}>
      <Box sx={boxStyle}>
        <AvatarEditor
          ref={cropRef}
          image={src}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          border={50}
          borderRadius={150}
          color={[0, 0, 0, 0.72]}
          scale={slideValue / 10}
          rotate={0}
        />

        {/* MUI Slider */}
        <Slider
          min={10}
          max={50}
          sx={{
            margin: "0 auto",
            width: "80%",
            color: "cyan"
          }}
          size="medium"
          defaultValue={slideValue}
          value={slideValue}
          onChange={(e:any) => setSlideValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            padding: "10px",
            border: "3px solid white",
            background: "black"
          }}
        >
          <Button
            size="small"
            sx={{ marginRight: "10px", color: "white", borderColor: "white" }}
            variant="outlined"
            onClick={(e:any) => setModalOpen(false)}
          >
            cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            sx={{ background: "#5596e6" }}
            size="small"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleSave}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

// Container
const Cropper = () => {
  // image src
  const [src, setSrc] = useState<string>();

  // preview
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

  // modal state
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  // ref to control input element
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  // handle Click
  const handleInputClick = (e:any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputRef.current?.click();
  };
  // handle Change
  const handleImgChange = (e:any) => {
    setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>React Avatar Cropper</h1>
        <hr />
      </header>
      <main className="container">
        <CropperModal
          modalOpen={modalOpen}
          src={src}
          setPreview={setPreview}
          setModalOpen={setModalOpen}
        />
        <a href="/" onClick={handleInputClick}>
          <FcAddImage className="add-icon" />
        </a>
        <small>Click to select image</small>
        <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          ref={inputRef}
          onChange={handleImgChange}
        />
        <div className="img-container">
          <img
            src={
              preview ||
              " https://www.signivis.com/img/custom/avatars/member-avatar-01.png"
            }
            alt=""
            width="200"
            height="200"
          />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cropper;
```

Comment: useRef(null) is returning cropRef, where cropRef.current has type never.  But you don't show all the code so that's all can be said.

Comment: @CraigHicks i edit and add the full code above.do you know how to solve the error?

Comment: You explicitly set cropRef value to null. If you add generic types not just set the value to null, it will recognise it can be other values as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. Use `InstanceType<typeof AvatarEditor>` as the generic parameter for the `useRef` hook.

Option 2. From the official [demo](https://github.com/mosch/react-avatar-editor/blob/669e1422036fdd34ae7024d8237834ce82217dbe/packages/demo/src/App.tsx#L37C36-L37C48), we can see `React.createRef<AvatarEditor>()`, so we can use `useRef<AvatarEditor>(null)` as well.

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import AvatarEditor from "react-avatar-editor";

const CropperModal = ({ src, modalOpen, setModalOpen, setPreview }: { src: any; modalOpen: any; setModalOpen: any; setPreview: any }) => {
    const [slideValue, setSlideValue] = useState(10);
    const cropRef = useRef<InstanceType<typeof AvatarEditor>>(null);
    // or
    // const cropRef = useRef<AvatarEditor>(null);

    //handle save
    const handleSave = async () => {
        if (cropRef.current !== null) {
            const dataUrl = cropRef.current.getImage().toDataURL();
            const result = await fetch(dataUrl);
            const blob = await result.blob();
            setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            setModalOpen(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <AvatarEditor
            ref={cropRef}
            image={src}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            border={50}
            borderRadius={150}
            color={[0, 0, 0, 0.72]}
            scale={slideValue / 10}
            rotate={0}
        />
    );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/77371451-vpvwsn?file=/src/example.tsx)

package versions:

- react-avatar-editor: 13.0.0
- @types/react-avatar-editor: 13.0.1